# cut the first word (from a string) that matches the pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string, winforms

I have a sentence:

> "This 'is' just an example"

I need to cut the word between first ' ' characters.

Up until now, I was using following Regex method:

```
string name_only = Regex.Match("This 'is' just an example", @"\'([^)]*)\'").Groups[1].Value;
```

> **Result**: is

and it worked perfectly fine, until another ' appeared:

> "This 'is' just an e'xample"

now I'm getting:

> **Result**: is' just an e

how do I fix this issue (other than iterating using the "for" cycle and finding first two inexes of character ' and then cutting the word using the substring) ?

Comment: such a *greedy* regex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your regex acts in a greedy way and if you change it to the following it will work:

```
@"\'([^)]*?)\'"
```

Comment: thank you sir! I cant believe that "?" can make such a big difference. Your answer perfectly solved the problem! (P.S. I will accept the answer in 4 minutes when it's allowed)

Answer (score 1):

By default regular expression follow the "leftmost longest rule": the match the leftmost, longest substring possible.

I'd be inclined to make the regular expression more specific about what it should match, thus:

```
'(([^']|(''))*)'
```

That should match:

- The lead-in single-quote character, followed by
- zero or more instances of

  - a single character other than a single-quote character, or
  - an "escaped" single-quote character: two consecutive single-quote characters,
- followed by the lead-out single-quote character.

$0 then gives you the entire match, and $1 the contents of the matched quoted value, exclusive of the lead-in/lead-out quotes.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx#Greedy

> ### Greedy and Lazy Quantifiers
>
> A number of the quantifiers have two  versions:
>
> 1. A greedy version.
>
>    A greedy quantifier tries to match an element as many times as possible.
> 2. A non-greedy (or lazy) version.
>
>    A non-greedy quantifier tries to match an element as few times as possible. You can turn a greedy quantifier into a lazy quantifier by simply adding a ?.